# How to avoid counting loop iterations in JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, es6-promise

I have recently started using promises so I can, for example, wait until I update a database with x number of records before executing the next function. I find myself counting loop iterations in order to resolve the promise at the right time. For example:

```js
var updateAccounts = function(accounts) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var counter = 0;
      accounts.forEach(function(account) {

        db.collection('accounts').update({
          name: account.name
        }, {
          $set: {
            balance: account.balance
          }
        });
        counter++
        if (counter == accounts.length) {
          resolve('accounts updated');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return promise;
}
```

Is there a way to wait until a loop is finished without counting the iterations? It just feels sort of hacky, but I'm not sure if it's really an issue or not.

Comment: you're not waiting for the updates to complete. The loop is sync, the updates are not. They happen in paralell while the loop has long finished. Check out [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Is this mongodb? mongoose?

Comment: @Thomas so you mean promise.all, and each update is a promise?

Comment: @trincot this is mongodb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

Basically this means that a `Promise` should track the outcome of a single async operation.

However, in your example, you've executed multiple async operations (i.e., `db.collection('accounts').update(...)`) inside one `Promise`. You've had to resort to an interation count to track completeness rather than relying on the promise to do that.

To resolve this issue (pun intended :D), each of your async requests should have their own `Promise`.

Since you have multiple updates and therefore multiple promises, you can use a `Promise.all` to capture when all the promises have completed successfully.

Here's a quick adaptation of your code example:

```
var updateAccounts = function(accounts) {
    var promises = [];
    accounts.forEach(function(account) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            db.collection('accounts').update({
              name: account.name
            }, {
              $set: {
                balance: account.balance
              }
            });
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(arrPromises) { 
        console.log("All promises resolved.");
    }).catch(function(failedPromise) {
        console.log("Something failed.");
    });

}
```

The only thing missing from my example is invoking `resolve` after `db.collection('accounts').update(...)` executes successfully. After the update completes successfully you must invoke `resolve`, or if the update fails you must invoke `reject`. This is what tells the promise it has finished.

My code example won't work without that, but it's not clear from your original code example where one should specify a callback for `db.collection('accounts').update(...)` -- so I've omitted it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try after the foreach?

```js
var updateAccounts = function(accounts) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      ...
      accounts.forEach(function(account) {
        ...
      });
    <---Here<--
    }
  });
  return promise;
}
```

It seems odd to be checking for completion of the foreach inside the loop. Maybe you want to make sure the accounts array has some elements? You could check it for zero or non-zero length outside the loop too.

Comment: I think I don't understand async bs sync but basically I want to make sure the loop has completed before moving onto the next function. What's the best way to do this? Does foreach do this by default?

Comment: I ended up de-selecting other answer and selecting this one. You were right, I could just resolve after the loop. for some reason I had an experience which made me think I have to count the loop, which is not true. Thank you, you just saved me a ton of time!

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. I highly recommend that you re-read the answer below.

Comment: Thanks Randall. It should probably have been a comment. Of course you're right just checking all the iterations are done won't tell you a bunch of async operations are complete

Comment: About that, there don't seem to be any callbacks for async completion though. I wonder is promise being used as intended?